# Application failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, app-config

I have a c# application and I added a manifest to it and set it to an embedded resource because I didn't want it appearing alongside my exe.

I then changed my app.config file to be an embedded resource as well but my exe then didnt start up as it gave me the error:

"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.  Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe. tool for more detail"

I have since changed it back to 'Do not copy" and I'm still getting the same error.

I have also deleted my app.config file from my project and re-added it.  Not I get 2 config files:
**App.config** and
**MyExeName.config**

How can I fix this??

Answer (score 2):

We found that our MyExeName.config had a comment block that was NOT CLOSED - thus making the rest of the .config file from that point onward one big comment!